# How to get domain name in vbscript for windows 2012 server R2?

Tags: vbscript

This worked in windows 2008 server R2, but not on windows 2012 server R2.  What is the equivalent in 2012?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>AD Manager</title>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
<!--
Sub Validate        
    Dim objSysInfo, owsh
    Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set owsh = CreateObject("WScript.Network")  
    username = owsh.username
    domain2 = objSysInfo.DomainShortName    <==== This is the line that fails
    document.getElementById("UserName").value =  domain2 & "\" & username
    document.getElementById("Password").value = "1234"
    document.getElementById("frmADManager").submit()
End Sub
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Validate()">
<form id="frmADManager" action="ProcessLogin.asp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="UserName" name="UserName" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="Password" name="Password" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be mixing VBScript with JavaScript in a possibly awkward way.

Here is one method that should work with either OS. There are many ways you could achieve this in a single language. I am surprised that the code you were using actually works on Windows 2008 R2 (yes, I know it does - I just tested it).

Take a look at this article for more information on how you can mix client side JavaScript with VBScript on the same page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260861(v=vs.60).aspx

In this example, we have split your VBScript and JavaScript into separate scripts, where one calls the other.

Tested to work on Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 2012 Server.

**NOTE: I do not recommend storing passwords like this in a production environment. Anyone can intercept this password as it loading client side. Presumably you are also using HTTP - the password will be visible in clear text. Consider a more secure alternative - as I am not sure why you are doing this or where you are feeding these credentials, I can't offer you a suggestion as to how to change things.**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>AD Manager</title>
        <script language="vbscript">
            function getDomainInfo()
                Dim objSysInfo, owsh
                Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
                Set owsh = CreateObject("WScript.Network")  
                username = owsh.username
                getDomainInfo = objSysInfo.DomainShortName & "\" & owsh.username
            End function
        </script>
        <script language="javascript">
            function validate()
            {
                document.getElementById("UserName").value =  getDomainInfo();
                document.getElementById("Password").value = "1234";
                document.getElementById("frmADManager").submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="validate()">
        <form id="frmADManager" action="ProcessLogin.asp" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="UserName" name="UserName" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" id="Password" name="Password" value="" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```